# Changing a user's email/password in Firebase 3 for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm looking for the new class and methods that replace 'changeEmailForUser' and 'changePasswordForUser' on the Firebase class after today's major update.  I assume they're now a part of FIRAuth, but I can't seem to find anything.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs are a bit confusing but at the bottom of the "Manage Users" section which is under "iOS" which is under "Authentication" which is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)

According to the docs, to update a user's email address:

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

[user updateEmail:@"user@example.com" completion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
  if (error) {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // Email updated.
  }
}];
```

and for password:

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
NSString *newPassword = [yourApp getRandomSecurePassword];

[user updatePassword:newPassword completion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
  if (error) {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // Password updated.
  }
}];
```

other important information regarding emails for password resets are all at the link given above.

Comment: It is to be noted that Firebase will often ask you to authenticate the user again before calling this method. They have a dedicated method to this purpose but you can also simply logout-login the user before asking him to change his password.

Comment: Thanks for Your Help . After update the password do I need to sign in again?